# A query that does not display duplicate data in a 1:N relationship table

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, there is table A and table B. A and B have a 1:N relationship.

a has multiple b's, and if this is left joined, as many as the number of b's in a are created. But I only want to see one a.

I wrote the query like this. However, as many mem_names are still created as many as b.

```
    select DISTINCT a.mem_name, b.*
    from member a left join product b
    on a.mem_name = b.username
    ;
```

How can I solve this?

My current result looks like this:

| a.mem_name | b.col1 | b.col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mem1 | 10 | 20 |
| mem1 | 30 | 40 |
| mem2 | 50 | 60 |
| mem2 | 70 | 80 |

while the desired result looks like this:

| a.mem_name | b.col1 | b.col2 | b.col1 | b.col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mem1 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| mem2 | 50 | 60 | 70 | 80 |

Comment: An `a` has multiple `b`. You want to show one row per `a`. So, which of its `b` do you want to show in that row?

Comment: Or, if you are talking about a display thing, i.e. you want to show all `a`/`b` rows, but suppress `a.mem_name` after its first occurrence in the result (and repace it with NULL), this is something you shouldn't do in SQL, but in your application or Website. (It is possible, though, with `LAG`.) Your request would become clear, did you add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: `DISTINCT` would remove duplicate rows, but it is unlikely you have any duplicate rows, where all values are the same.

Comment: Can you look at the photos you added? The result of the select. As you can see from the photo, if you put two b's in a, two a's with two b's are created. What I want to appear on the screen is the mem_name column of a, and all columns of b. 
As you answered, even if you use distinct, duplicates do not seem to be removed because the values ​​in column b are not all duplicates. In this case, can't I just process the data the way I want with sql?

Comment: This doesn't look like a query result. A query result has columns, while you are only showing rows. As mentioned, display things should be cared for in the app, not in SQL.

Comment: I've added result tables to your request. Please edit the second one to show the desired output.

Comment: Added. The result I want is that, if only sql can't handle it, I'm thinking of modifying the backend.

Comment: As SQL returns tables of before-known columns, you would have to know the maximum number of `b` matching an `a`.  With two columns in `b` and, say, a maximum of five `b` per `a`, you would write a query with ten `b` columns ( 2 x 5 = 10). But it's much better to keep this dynamic and not do this in SQL, but in the calling app instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! We are going to fix the front. I just found the right way. Thanks for the kind reply :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are confusing SQL with a report writing tool.  Your query is asking for a data set that **always** has the a.mem_name **and** all the elements from b for all combinations of a and b that satisfy `a.mem_name = b.username`.  No matter how you ask SQL you cannot sometimes include 'table a' data and other times not.

How you choose to display this result set is another matter.  There are report writing tools that allow this blanking of data when it is ordered correctly.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Let's search for that too.

Answer (score -2):

because you don't know principle of `distinct`.
b.* cause the question.

you need replace with `group by`, like

```sql
select a.mem_name, b.*
    from member a left join product b
    on a.mem_name = b.username
group by a.mem_name
```

Attention: this sql statement cannot be executed on SqlServer, but it's valid and can executed on MySQL. and random row of table b relationed with a will be showed.

Comment: And you don't know the principle  of `GROUP BY`. An `a` has multiple `b`. So, which of its `b` do you think your query will show? Your query is invalid.

Comment: this sql is invalid in SqlServer, but it's valid in MySQL, did you runed it in MySQL??

Comment: It is not really *valid* in MySQL. MySQL is supposed to detect that there is more than one possible `b` per `a`. Depending on the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode being set or not and depending on how well MySQL does the job, it will either reject this query or apply `ANY_VALUE` on all `b` columns silently (i.e. give you arbitrary results). It is generally considered a kind of flaw that MySQL lets slip invalid queries thus. Inexperienced users may think their query is valid, while it is actually not. Yours isn't. I suggest you switch to MySQL 8 and have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY set to get optimal help.

Comment: sorry, you are right, I should advise standard SQL for beginner.